# How to handle multiple but similar record types

Tags: haskell

So let's say I have the following nearly identical type declarations. The types are related to each other in that MyType2 is a "processed" version of MyType1.

```
data MyType1 = MyType1 {
   field1 :: Maybe Text
   manyOtherFields :: Maybe Whatever
}

data MyType2 = MyType2 {
  field1 :: Text,
  manyOtherFields :: Whatever
}
```

Initially field1 is a Maybe because the data is coming from user input. Once processed however it becomes a Just value.

This pattern of processing Maybes into Justs is likely to be repeated 10's or even 100's of times throughout my program with potentially many similar combinations describing variations of essentially the same entity at different processing stages.

How do I avoid duplicating my type definitions for all the similar combinations ?

Further explanation:

In my actual program, the problem is accepting a file as input from a web form. When the form is received by my code the file input field is a Maybe FilePath, so I have a data type like:

```
data Media = Media {
  filePath :: Maybe FilePath
  altText :: Text,
}
```

Once the input has been processed I'd need a new data type:

```
data Media2 = Media2 {
  filePath :: FilePath
  altText :: Text,
  height :: Int,
  width :: Int
}
```

This seems ugly and impractical since similar patterns will be repeated over and over in my program. It's quite possible I'll need a Media3 (and 4) not to mention all the other entities and their variations.

Answer (score 4):

I forgot the name of this technique... however, here it is:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Functor.Identity

data MyType f = MyType
   { field1 :: f Text
   , manyOtherFields :: f Whatever
   }
type MyType1 = MyType Maybe
type MyType2 = MyType Identity
```

The price to pay is to have an `Identity` constructor wrapping the data when it's fully processed.

For instance:

```
x :: MyType1  -- partially processed
x = MyType{field1 = Nothing, manyOtherFields = Just whatever}

y :: MyType2  -- fully processed
y = MyType{field1 = Identity someText, manyOtherFields = Identity whatever}
```

Comment: Thanks, but ... my problem is more complicated than that.

Of the manyOtherFields, some will be Maybe's, some won't - at different stages of the program. I'm trying to avoid creating many near clones for each possible variation.

Comment: @Simon You could try the [Data Types a la Carte](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~wss/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf) approach.

Comment: @Simon I fear that you need a type which is so much parametrized it's actually a tuple (perhaps under another name).

Comment: @bheklilr - that link broken :/

Comment: @chi: what i'm doing in principle is really simple. I wonder if there's an inherent weakness with Haskells type system? 

The real world is full of maybe values (nulls in databases, empty form fields etc) such that I'd need to use Maybe *almost everywhere* but that would be nightmarish and ugly. Alternatively I can force the software to "resolve the maybes" but then I end up with different types to acting as "gateways" to different processing stages.

Comment: @Simon Are you trying to avoid using `Maybe`s because you're used to having null values in other languages?  The `Maybe` values really aren't difficult to work with in Haskell when you use the tools provided by `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad`, along with the combinators in `Data.Maybe`.  Yes, the real world is full of nulls, which is why Haskell's type system allows you to encode that fact into your data types with `Maybe`.  This helps you avoid null pointer errors, a serious problem in more traditional languages.

Comment: @bheklilr - basically, yes. except it's more having to repetitively use fromMaybe *everywhere* to deal with possibility of a Nothing. This is especially annoying when I've done the processing to ensure that a value exists.

Comment: @Simon Could you possibly make a gist/pastebin/whatever of an actual use case here?  It could just be that there's a better way to make it less painful, maybe a combinator or technique that you're unaware of.  I'm not saying that's the case, it's just hard to know without seeing real code.

Comment: @bheklilr - posted an example here ->  http://lpaste.net/132675
I've added explanatory comments starting on line 54

Comment: @Simon It actually doesn't look like `digestive-functors` supports a default file name being shown on the form (although this is just what I've gleaned from reading the docs and source for the library, I've never used it before). But if you did want to at least provide a default you could do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/ab9b17001cd3cbbe8b32). It compiles at least, and the introduction of `<?` (think "feeds a maybe" as a mnemonic) along with some alignment results in a very readable block of code. I can't guarantee that `fileWithDefault` works, but it should in theory.

Comment: @Simon I also chose to use `RecordWildCards`, but it isn't necessary.  Without it you'd just add `m` at the end of all of those lines and replace `Media{..}` with `m`, which isn't bad either.  When you have lots of record fields it can come in handy, though.

Comment: @Simon Nope, that won't set a default.  That's rather obnoxious... I would file an issue on [github](https://github.com/jaspervdj/digestive-functors) to say that `fmap (fromMaybe defaultFile) file` does not do what one might expect, and the `defaultFile` value is dropped when converting to a `View`.

Comment: @bheklilr - many thanks, that's very enlightening. will give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

You give three data types in your gist:

```
data Media = Media {
    mediaId :: Int
  , mediaName :: Text
  , mediaFilePath :: FilePath
  , mediaMimeType :: Text
  , mediaHash :: Text
  , mediaWidth :: Int
  , mediaHeight :: Int
  , mediaCreated :: UTCTime
  , mediaUpdated :: UTCTime
}
data Media2 = Media2 {
    mediaId :: Int
  , mediaName :: Text
  , mediaFilePath :: Maybe FilePath
  , mediaMimeType :: Text
  , mediaHash :: Text
  , mediaWidth :: Int
  , mediaHeight :: Int
  , mediaCreated :: UTCTime
  , mediaUpdated :: UTCTime
}
data Media3= Media3 {
    media3Id :: Int
  , media3Name :: Text
  , media3FilePath :: FilePath
  , media3NewFilePath :: Maybe FilePath
  , media3MimeType :: Text
  , media3Hash :: Text
  , media3Width :: Int
  , media3Height :: Int
  , media3Created :: UTCTime
  , media3Updated :: UTCTime
}
```

...and complain that these violate the DRY principle (and I agree!). One simple solution is to split out the shared parts, thus:

```
data Metadata = Metadata
  { id :: Int
  , name :: Text
  , mimeType :: Text
  , hash :: Text
  , width :: Int
  , height :: Int
  , created :: UTCTime
  , updated :: UTCTime
  }
```

Then you have a few options for parameterizing the remaining bits. One choice is to have type modifiers; for example:

```
data Located   a = Located   { location :: FilePath, locatedValue :: a }
data Motion    a = Motion    { oldLocation, newLocation :: FilePath, motionValue :: a }
data UILocated a = UILocated { uiField :: Maybe FilePath, uilocatedValue :: a }
```

so that the old `Media` type, for example, would now be a `Located Metadata`. Another choice would be to have a sum type for locations:

```
data Location
    = OnDisk FilePath
    | Nowhere
    | Moving FilePath FilePath
```

Then you could use `(Metadata, Location)` as your type for all three, or put the location in a field of `Metadata`. This loses some static checking, but may be convenient in some situations.

Yet a third option is to add a polymorphic field to the metadata type:

```
data Metadata a = Metadata
  { id :: Int
  , name :: Text
  , mimeType :: Text
  , hash :: Text
  , width :: Int
  , height :: Int
  , created :: UTCTime
  , updated :: UTCTime
  , extra :: a
  }
```

so that your old `Media` type, for example, would now be `Metadata FilePath`, and `Media3` would be `Metadata (FilePath, Maybe FilePath)`.